# .NET 4.5 async await and overloaded methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have an async method:

```
public async Task<UserLoginExResult> LoginExAsync(CustomTable exRequest, string language, bool throwEx = true)
{
    UserLoginExResult result = await UserService.LoginExAsync(UserGroup, language, TimezoneOffset, GetDeviceInfo(), GetLoginProperties(), exRequest);

    ProcessLoginResult(result, false, throwEx);

    return result;
}
```

And an overload:

```
public Task<UserLoginExResult> LoginExAsync(CustomTable exRequest, bool throwEx = true)
{
    return LoginExAsync(exRequest, Language.ID, throwEx);
}
```

I'm not sure if I should mark the overloaded one (the one with fewer parameters) as `async` and use `await`? I guess I should not but can you tell me what whould happen if I would do that? I'm quite lost in here and not really sure what `Task` it would wait for? Would it create an extra `Task` or `await` doesn't create a new `Task`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, there's little benefit in using an async method when it's *just* going to wrap and unwrap an existing one. It's fine to just have a "normal" method here, delegating to the "real" async method.

(They're not *quite* the same - for example, if the `UserService.LoginExAsync` method throws an exception rather than returning a failed task, the async/await version will just return a failed task, whereas the other version will *also* throw immediately.)

Comment: But is there any harm in adding it?  What is the cost of the overhead?  Or does the compiler optimize it away?

Comment: @Matt: The cost is that of setting up a trivial state machine, basically. It will also change how any exceptions thrown when creating the task get propagated, so they're not 100% equivalent. But the compiler definitely doesn't optimize one to the other.

Comment: Thanks.  You helped me settle an argument before I even had to have it. :)

Comment: Actually, I found a case where apparently [it does matter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28053323/634824).  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: @MattJohnson: I've modified my description to indicate one difference, though I'm not sure it's relevant in your case. Will look at that now.

Answer (score 11):

The `async` keyword only enables the `await` keyword. In your case, you can return the `Task` directly, so there's no need for the `async` keyword. `async` would only add overhead without adding any value.

For more information, see [Stephen Toub's Zen of Async talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T). He addresses this situation directly.

Answer (score 5):

It would really only be worth doing if you were doing additional work in your overload, e.g.

```
public async Task<UserLoginExResult> LoginExAsync(CustomTable exRequest, bool throwEx = true)
{
    Task<UserLoginExResult> result = await LoginExAsync(exRequest, Language.ID, throwEx);

    //Do some work here that depends on the result from the task completeion

    return result;
}
```

But as you are not, it isn't!

Answer (score 2):

The overload doesn't need to be marked as `async` as it doesn't internally await anything, so therefore there's nothing for the compiler to rewrite.