# Why do async unit tests fail when the async/await keywords aren't used?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, async-await, mstest

According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13086258/634824), there should be no difference between the following two methods:

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}

public Task Foo()
{
    return DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

Actually, it would seem that for very simple methods, the invocation *without* the async/await keywords would be preferred, as they remove some overhead.

However, this apparently doesn't always work in unit tests.

**MSTest**

```
[TestClass]
public class AsyncTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public Task Test2()
    {
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }
}
```

**NUnit**

```
[TestFixture]
public class AsyncTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    [Test]
    public Task Test2()
    {
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }
}
```

**XUnit**

```
public class AsyncTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    [Fact]
    public Task Test2()
    {
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }
}
```

- In all cases, `Test1` passes.
- In MSTest, `Test2` shows up in the test runner, but it doesn't run.
- In NUnit, `Test2` is ignored, with the message:

  > Test method has non-void return type, but no result is expected
- In XUnit, `Test2` passes.

Since the tasks are still awaitable in all cases, what is it about the `async` keyword that affects the NUnit and MSTest test runners?  Perhaps some reflection issue?

Comment: Actually, there's [certain difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631/1768303) between `Test1` and `Test2` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like those test runners may be using reflection to check whether the method returning `Task` really *is* an async method. That doesn't mean the method would behave differently *if they were run* - but they're just not being run.

It's like saying that:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
private string name;
public Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
```

They're logically the same in terms of behaviour, but if you try hard enough with reflection, you can tell the difference. In this particular case there are other more subtle differences, but the same general principle applies.

It looks like in the current NUnit code (at the time of this writing) the detection is in [`AsyncInvocationRegion.cs`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/51079b29113b32447d89c47c5e914f98c5875540/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/AsyncInvocationRegion.cs#L81).

Admittedly it's at least *unusual* to write a unit test returning a `Task` but without using an async method - but far from impossible.

Comment: I see.  So NUnit specifically expects the method to have been decorated with `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` by the compiler.  I guess that explains it.  MSTest is likely doing something similar.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Of course you could add that attribute yourself, I suspect - just to fool it. Possibly worth trying just to see what MSTest does...

Comment: Yep.  Added `[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(Task))]` and now passes under both MSTest and NUnit.  Though I think I'll just stick to async/await keywords.  :)